# Having hard time to start GCE VM with GPU in us-east-1

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are having problem to start a simple GCE VM with GPU in us-central-1. I am wondering if anyone experience the same thing. The error we got is below:

Instance 'instance-group-2-vc37' creation failed: The resource 'projects/xxxxx-xxxx-858/zones/us-central1-a/acceleratorTypes/nvidia-tesla-k80' was not found (when acting as 'xxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com')

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's trying to access a resource in `us-central1-a`, when you mention `us-east1`.  Where does the error show up when you attempt to create the VM?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyRodi The post is edited. us-central-1 is the one i should say.

Comment: The error message is copied from when i mouse over the yellow triangle during instance creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCE doesn't offer GPUs in us-central1. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/) list which regions GPUs are available in.

Cloud ML Engine is a separate product and not what you are using here.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, My apology. The GPUs Available zones are: us-west1-b, us-east1-c, us-east1-d, europe-west1-b, europe-west1-d, asia-east1-a. I was able to create one in us-east1-c